# Display UTC Datetime to user defined timezone

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, timezone, utc

I have dates in UTC in database, and I have the user timezone in their preferences table.

I have an extension method to convert from UTC to user time:

```
public static DateTime ToClientTime(this DateTime dt)
{
     TimeZoneInfo cstZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("SA Pacific Standard Time"); //Hardcoded timezone
     return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dt, cstZone);
}
```

As you can see in the code below, for now it has a hardcoded time zone name, and I should pass by parameter that value (passing the user timezone).

In CurrentThread I set the user culture, so all code in this request behaves in that culture (date formats, resources, number formats). **There is a way to store the user's timezone in a global object like CurrentThread or something like that?**

What I'm trying to accomplish is avoid passing the time zone to the above extension method, and instead get the timezone from a global object like CurrentThread. The extension method will be called from Controller code and also from Views.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for.  What information do you actually have, what are you storing, and what are you wanting to achieve?  Show examples with data and code please.

Comment: Store all your times in UTC, and just covert them in your views into whatever you want

Comment: @MattJohnson, please check my edit, hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Seems like you are asking about how to store *anything* in the current thread.  Could be time zone id, could be some random string.  You may want to search/ask on that separately.  Do keep in mind that with modern async/await code, you're not guaranteed continuations occur on the same thread.  This can be problematic for older things like `ThreadLocal` and `ThreadStatic`.  You might try the logical call context (`CallContext.LogicalSetData` / `CallContext.LogicalGetData`).

Comment: Thanks Matt... The current thread was an example.. but I get the idea. If you post your comment as answer I can mark it as answered.

Answer (score -1):

You have a base time like UTC, right? Not you have a user specified time zone in data base. So now you can either add or subtract from the UTC time zone depending on the need.

Probably addition can provide a simple solution.
Example:

```
Name ----------TimeZone
------------------------
Nick  ------- UTC - 6
Hary  ------- UTC + 1
```

So, if the current UTC time is 7 PM or 18:00 then

```
Nick = 18-6 = 12 / 12 PM
Harry = 18+1 = 19 / 8PM
```

Comment: Time Zone != Offset.  Also, .NET has plenty of functionality for this built in without resorting to manual arithmetic.